# Need Help on chrome drive run test, everytime i run test I Agree appear and test stops

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

hello everyone i am new .

last night i was trying to do a test looking at tutorial but when i start run test chrome opens up at the screen "before you continue to Google Search " Customise or  I agree screen , test does not go further. i will post screen shot too, i have been looking for answer for few hours on internet but i can not find any. enter image description ,no matter what for test i run test stops when chrome browser pops up .i have downloaded in correct way chrome drive

[everytime run test it stops at Customise I Agree screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQu2c.jpg)

[everytime run test it stops at Customise I Agree screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COkT2.jpg)

[everytime run test it stops at Customise I Agree screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyLkV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, Selenium is better for opening a website and not searching. If you have a website in mind I would just put in the URL instead of searching. You could do:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q={thing you are searching here}
```

If you need any more help let me know!

Comment: yes i definitely need help, i mean i have wrote test code and when i run test chrome pops up at that screen which is in the screen shot and stops there, i used yahoo.com , it keep asking me to customise or I Agree . i mean when i run test chrome pops up and stop, because i need to click either I Agree or Customise, it wont test further.

Comment: Hey is this with chromedriver.exe?